# Java - Regex - Months requiring 1-12

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to build a regex for a field containing the number of months, of course, this needs to be only numbers 1-12. However, new to regex this is a bit new to me and I just need to check I'm right. It seems to work alright. Although, am I correct in assuming the range here 1-12 allows any number in this range, I only ask as I've only ever seen it done with 0-9 before.

```
[1-12]{1,2}
```

Comment: This needs a regex? Why not try to convert it to a date and deal with the failure? Or have an array of 1-12 and check that the value is in there? Or check that the number is an integer > 0 and < 13?

Comment: I think that regex means "The number 1 or the number 2, 1 or 2 times".

Comment: That's not how character classes work. The range notation (`[x-y]`) is a _character_ range. Agreed with @Ben, regex is *not* the right tool for this.

Comment: Is it just me, or is there just too much effort spent telling the OP the question he asked isn't the question he wants to ask?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This might do.  Two digits or one digit

```
1[0-2]|[1-9]
```

Edit: If you're worried about numbers like 55 use this:

```
^(1[0-2]|[1-9])$
```

Adding the `^` and `$` means start and end of string.  Use https://regex101.com as a good learning tool.

Comment: This isn't acceptable. If I entered "55", the first digit would be allowed.

Answer (score 10):

Don't just a regex. Just don't. [Parse the string to an `int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), and check that the value is in range.

```
boolean isMonthInRange(String monthInput)
{
    try
    {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(monthInput, 10);
        return value >= 1 && value <= 12;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Since this is Java, there are a whole pile of libraries we could throw at this problem instead of rolling a custom solution. At the very least, don't use magic numbers (`1` and `12`) in the condition.

Answer (score 5):

Another suggestion:

```
\b(?:1[0-2]|[1-9])\b
```

It's possible that you don't need to check the word boundaries if you allow just the full match - but otherwise the regexp. in previous answers would match e.g. 1 and 3 in 13 as two separate matches.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do fine: `(^[1-9]$)|(^0[1-9]|1[0-2]$)`

you can insert 1-12 and also 01, 02 ...

Comment: this matches 111

Answer (score 1):

```
/(1[0-2]|[1-9])/
```

Though as others have said, there are probably better ways. Just checking if the value, when evaluated as an integer, is < 1 or > 12 would work as well (and be simpler for those unfamiliar with regular expressions to understand). (Edit: Like MДΓΓ БДLL's answer.)

Comment: This isn't acceptable. If I entered "55", the first digit would be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:

```
[1-9]|10|11|12
```

Comment: This would allow the string 1101112.

Comment: You need alternation to make this work: `[1-9]|[10]|[11]|[12]` though it's still a rubbish way of doing this.

Comment: MДΓΓ БДLL, even that pattern allows 0 to pass and is just generally odd. Perhaps you meant `([1-9]|10|11|12)`?

Comment: Well, [edit your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10260202/edit) then. @GarrettAlbright of course, you're right. Thanks for the correction. I copypasta'd without thinking. Yet another hint that regex is just not the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

And for an HTML/JavaScript solution, the following regex could be used for an HTML input pattern attribute, to enforce mm/dd/yyyy format, where mm is 1-12, dd is 1-31, and yyyy is 1930-1999...

```
(?:1[0-2]|[1-9])\/(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/(19[3-9]{1}[0-9]{1})
```

...and, along with some CSS to provide visual cues, it might be used like this:

```css
input::placeholder {
    color: rgb(46, 163, 242);
    font-style: italic;
}
input:focus {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
}
input:required:invalid, input:focus:invalid {
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 159, 159) !important;
    background: white;
}
input:required:valid {
    background: rgba(196, 255, 214, .5) !important;
    color: black !important;
}

section.form-layout input { 
    width: 120px;
    height: 27px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(46, 163, 242);
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(46, 163, 242);
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="form-layout">
    <p>Enter your DOB <span style="font-style: italic;">(mm/dd/yyyy)</span>:</p>
    <input required id="dob-1" placeholder="Date of Birth" type="text" pattern="(?:1[0-2]|[1-9])\/(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/(19[3-9]{1}[0-9]{1})" autocomplete="off">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want months in the format of 01 - 12, then I would use the below snippet

```
^(0[1-9]|10|11|12)$
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this would only accept "01", "02", etc. but makes "1", "2" invalid. Probably it's a good idea to cater for both these inputs.